# How to convert all suitable values to int

Tags: python

I have a large dictionary of about 100 million key/value pairs.

I would like to convert all the values which can easily be converted to ints.

For example if I start with:

```
b = {'one': '001', 'two': 2, 'three': 'three'}
```

I would like the result to be

```
b2 = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 'three'}
```

If I simply iterate over b and cast all the values to int I get an error when it gets to 'three'.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `try/except` to catch the ValueError thrown by `int()` when `three` is passed in. Example -

```
b2 = {}
for k,v in b.items():
    try:
        b2[k] = int(v)
    except ValueError:
        b2[k] = v
```

You should note, this would also truncate floats to integer , but I am guessing that is expected behavior.

---

Demo -

```
>>> b = {'one': '001', 'two': 2, 'three': 'three'}
>>> b2 = {}
>>> for k,v in b.items():
...     try:
...         b2[k] = int(v)
...     except ValueError:
...         b2[k] = v
...
>>> b2
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 'three'}
```

Comment: Slow internet connection damn you :)

Comment: I would ``pass`` when the ``exception`` is cached.

Comment: Why? OP needs that value in the `b2` dictionary as well right? If you pass, that key/value would not be there in the b2 dictionary.

Comment: upss , he wants another dict .. i thought was an in place conversion

Answer (score 2):

You need an external function to convert `string to int` here I have used `int_conversion` and have used `dict comprehension` to create the second dictionary

**Code:**

```
dic = {'one': '001', 'two': 2, 'three': 'three'}

def int_conversion(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except Exception:
        return value   
b2={key:int_conversion(value) for key,value in dic.iteritems()}
print b2
```

**Output:**

```
{'one': 1, 'three': 'three', 'two': 2}
```

Comment: @eleanora happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Though perhaps a little unpythonic you could test to see if is a digit before converting:

```
b2 = {k: int(v) if isinstance(v, str) and v.isdigit() else v for k, v in b.items()}
```

Comment: This would fail for `'two' : 2` , where the value is int, not string.

Comment: Good catch, you could extend the condition to include the test for being a str but this is getting more unpythonic :)

Comment: Don't try to cram everything on one line. Here, you want to take a good look at each value and decide how to proceed. For example, a string may be convertable to an int, or not (and isdigit() is the wrong test if it's negative). Wrap the attempted `int(s)` in a `try`, catch the exception and return the string unchanged. Maybe a float should not be converted to an int (losing precision). Maybe a null string is an acceptable zero. Write a convert_to_int(v) function that carefully does precisely what you want. By all means apply it in a one-liner.